# d3.js: append a span with glyphicon class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following piece of code is working properly. It draws me a circle. What I want is that inside this circle to draw a bootstrap glyphicon: `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>`

```
d3.json("relations", function(error, graph) {
    var links = svg.selectAll()
        .data(graph.links).enter();

    links        
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("r", circle_r)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

I have tried to do do the following continuing the previous code:

`links
   .append("span")
   .attr("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in")`

but the symbol does not render. I guess there is something about positioning it, because with firebug/inspector I can see the `<span>` settled.

Does anyone knows how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got this to work by adding the glyphicons like so:

```
link.append("svg:foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("y", "-7px")
    .attr("x", "-7px")
  .append("xhtml:span")
    .attr("class", "control glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in");
```

And by making the `.glyphicon`'s position static:

```
.control.glyphicon {
  position: static;
}
```

[Plnkr example here](http://embed.plnkr.co/RWDVeL330n1SSKlmqxkA/preview)

Comment: great, they are rendering now. But actualy now I am putting them inside an ``<a>`` tag, so they are a link. They are clickable. But when I do ``cursor: pointer`` in CSS, it's not working...wondering why...

Comment: Works for me when I add `cursor: pointer` to the `.control.glyphicon` CSS above.

Comment: yeah, nevermind, something else was generating my problem. Great, thanks

Comment: svg:foreignElement is not supported on IE, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject